# Return a dataset based on conditional with Highmaps

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, jquery-selectors, highmaps

[Take this demo as an example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/category-map/)

```
series : [{
    name: 'UTC',
    data: $.map(['IE', 'IS', 'GB', 'PT'], function (code) {
        return { code: code };
    })
}, {
    name: 'UTC + 1',
    data: $.map(['NO', 'SE', 'DK', 'DE', 'NL', 'BE', 'LU', 'ES', 'FR', 'PL', 'CZ', 'AT', 'CH', 'LI', 'SK', 'HU',
            'SI', 'IT', 'SM', 'HR', 'BA', 'YF', 'ME', 'AL', 'MK'], function (code) {
        return { code: code };
    })
}, {
    name: 'UTC + 2',
    data: $.map(['FI', 'EE', 'LV', 'LT', 'BY', 'UA', 'MD', 'RO', 'BG', 'GR', 'TR', 'CY'], function (code) {
        return { code: code };
    })
}, {
    name: 'UTC + 3',
    data: $.map(['RU'], function (code) {
        return { code: code };
    })
}]
```

Let's say, as an arbitrary example, I wanted to create an entry with `name: 'starts with A'` and I wanted the data object to contain all objects in `$.map` where `code.indexOf('A') == 0` (basically checking if the first character in `code` is an 'A'.

With pseudocode, this is how I would approach it, I'm just not sure how to execute it.

```
{
name: 'starts with A',
data: $.map(/* Select all entries somehow */, function (code) {
        if(code.indexOf('A') == 0)
            return { code: code };
    })
}
```

Comment: And what is incorrect in it, becase it will work properly.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Please see the comment in my second code snippet, I need code to add there.

Comment: But by select all entries you mean a all series, right? If yes you need to prepare your data in the preprocessing and then use in highcharts.

Comment: @SebastianBochan Please see the JSFiddle for more clarity...the data is taken straight from `Highcharts.maps['custom/europe']`. I'm looking for a way to select data without listing each individual object like 'FI', 'EE', 'LV', 'LT', etc...

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2hj2/